# CSS Animation: Rotate around X-axis?

Tags: css, animation, transform, css-animations

So I came around [this google doodle](https://www.google.com/doodles/new-horizons-pluto-flyby), and I was wondering how you can manage do that kind of a rotation with CSS (the google doodle is a gif). It looks like it only spins around one axis, if I make a rotation in CSS it rotates around x and y axis. Is this possible with 3D rotate (never used it so I don't know).

I've made a basic example in [JSfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ZanicL3/kfd0Ly57/).

HTML:

```
<div class="rotatediv">
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.rotatediv {
  background-color: red;
  width:500px;
  height:500px;
  animation-name:rotate_animation;
  animation-duration: 15s;
  animation-delay:0s;
  animation-iteration-count: infinite;
}

@keyframes rotate_animation {
  0% {transform: rotate(0deg);}
  100% {transform: rotate(360deg);}
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The trick is to put a div inside the rotatediv and to make rotatediv invisible by removing its background-color. Give the div inside rotatediv a background color instead.

Now position the div inside rotatediv with help of `position: absolute;`.
The parent div will rotate and the child div will rotate as well while keeping the same orientation of the parent.

```
<img src="https://placehold.it/300x300" />
<div class="rotatediv">
  <div class="object">
    <img src="https://placehold.it/30x30/000000" />
  </div>
</div>

.object {
  text-align: center;
}
img {
  position: absolute;
}

.rotatediv {
  width:300px;
  height:300px;
  animation-name:rotate_animation;
  animation-duration: 15s;
  animation-delay:0s;
  animation-iteration-count: infinite;
}

@keyframes rotate_animation {
  0% {transform: rotate(360deg);}
  100% {transform: rotate(0deg);}
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/r8r4hzq2/